# Override default url for author pages?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, author

So the default url to display a list of posts by a particular author looks like this:

`http://domain.com/author/{username}`

I am wondering how to change the 'author' in that url to something else?

I am working on a website for a charter school and they would like to allow each teacher to have a list of posts by "classroom". So the desired url would be

`http://domain.com/classroom/{username}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might wish to try..
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-author-base/

Hope that helps.. ;)

Comment: in that case, is there a way to list all authors under `http://domain.com/classroom` url?

Answer (score 16):

You can add this in your functions, and it will rewrite the slug from default "author" to "classroom",

```
function new_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_slug = 'classroom';
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
add_action('init', 'new_author_base');
```

hope it helps you

Comment: `flush_rules()` is quite expensive (in resources), so I would not call it on every page load. If you only do this for one site you can leave it out and just visit the *Permalinks* page, this will flush the rules too.

Comment: Yes @Jan Fabry, you are right, i have edit the answer now.
I wrote a better solution.

Comment: For anyone wondering whether to use this snippet or the plugin t31os mentioned: the plugin does exactly the same, but with an interface to change the URL part. Since you probably won't change it every month, this snippet in your `functions.php` is more than enough (and won't be disabled by accident).

Answer (score 1):

I use "Edit Author Slug" plugin for doing the same on my http://www.techcartnow.com/author/kapil-khandelwal/ WordPress Blog. I have modified "author slug" using this plugin.

"**[Edit Author Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/)**" plugin allows you to change both the author base (the ‘/author/’ portion of the author URLs), and the author slug (defaults to the username of the author).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your `functions.php`:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->author_base = "member"; // or whatever
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```