# Custom author url and page for another role

Tags: url-rewriting, user-roles, author, author-template

I would like to create a custom url and a separate or duplicate the author.php template for another custom role w/o using plugins.

I found this related topic but it just modify the author url

[Override default url for author pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4241/override-default-url-for-author-pages)

Something like:

`mydomain.com/author/foo`

for all the default roles and

`mydomain.com/member/john`

for the new custom role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can create a user roles and create a dynamic author base for each role from setting.
Use the below github repo: https://github.com/thebrandonallen/edit-author-slug

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Baikare Sandeep! preferably I don't want to use plugins and I have not tried it yet, but I can see the detail is straightforward and directly answers my requirements. Great find and resolved! 

Comment: Yes, but custom code will be issue to put it in the theme when new upgrade comes in future. So I think plugin is better way to hook the functionality. in WordPress

Comment: Ok so I tried it the only issue that I am getting so far is that it works both ways, so if you use another slug with another role it still works and not exclusively for that role.